# Postfix open relay

Tags: postfix, google, smtp, vulnerabilities

Greetings,

Google says that I'm originating too many emails from my IP. Since I NEVER uses this smtp to originate emails, I suspect my postfix is somewhat misconfigured, so that I have an open relay

```
google LOG entry:
Oct  8 06:29:29 domU-12-31-39-00-C1-66 postfix/smtp[15217]: 79B661A0CC: to=<hashimptil@gmail.com>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.219.30]:25, delay=423271, delays=423209/0.03/31/31, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.219.30] said: 421-4.7.0 [174.129.96.42] Our system has detected an unusual amount of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 blocked. Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html 421 4.7.0 to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. 6si2037492ewy.56 (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Is it possible to configure postfix in order to not allow originating emails from it? If positive, how? Otherwise, how can I fix my postfix configuration about the open relay issue?

postconf -o output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = fairlogic.com, legitima.com, bastos.org, sidon.com, localhost
myhostname = fairlogic.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

After googling a little, I figured out the problem:

1) cat /var/log/mail.log | grep "smtp[" | tail

```
Oct  8 11:47:00 domU-12-31-39-00-C1-66 postfix/smtp[24599]: 4C9521A0A4: to=<surinder.k.mehta@gmail.com>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.79.27]:25, delay=23543, delays=23481/0.01/31/31, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.79.27] said: 421-4.7.0 [174.129.96.42] Our system has detected an unusual amount of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 blocked. Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html 421 4.7.0 to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. 5si273044eyh.4 (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

based on the message id (4C9521A0A4 in this case), I can retrieve the message body:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/defer* -name 4C9521A0A4
/var/spool/postfix/defer/4/4C9521A0A4
/var/spool/postfix/deferred/4/4C9521A0A4
```

based on its contents, I figured out that someone was spamming me - and postfix tried to reply to the sender (telling "undelivered mail returned to sender"). So that it is not an exploit neither a postix misconfiguration. Now I shall disable this postfix notification, and my problem is gone.

Comment: The term for this is "backscatter." It may not be an exploit but it's definitely a problem. The Postfix site has a HOWTO on dealing with it at http://www.postfix.org/BACKSCATTER_README.html.

Comment: I wish that was MY problem! Following an upgrade, my long OK system became a genuine open relay!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have "permit_mynetworks" set and "my_networks" appears set correctly, it looks like postfix is not an open relay.  I would look for something else on your system sending email, like a hacked web service.

If the mail was really coming through your postfix, you'd see it in /var/log/mail.log.  If it's coming through a web service, look for suspicious entries in /var/log/apache2/access.log.
Otherwise you might just be rooted.

Update: You can also use http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/shopenrelaytest.php or similar to test if you're an open relay.

Answer (score 1):

Could block outgoing requests to port 25 until you've tracked it down? eg on linux with iptables

iptables  -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT

Answer (score 1):

Postfix does not seem to have a specific feature like sendmail's promiscuous_relay but if you add 0.0.0.0 to mynetworks, it should allow anyone to relay.

Comment: But this just relay, instead i need local delivery

Comment: Then thats not an open relay.

Comment: What do you mean by "Local delivery" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NAT any box behind your IP could be infected and sending spam.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need open relay ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay)), you should configure [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) and [smtpd_recipient_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions).

You can find several config samples on [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.net)

Comment: I know very well what's an open relay, i WANT it and i know why. This is not an answer.

Comment: are you wanting a remote user to be able to "bounce" mail thru your server or do you want your server to accept and locally deliver mail with any @destination? You might take a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/164105/how-to-catchall-email-to-a-single-user-mailbox-in-postfix/164115#164115 to see if it's what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want open relay try to leave blank [smtpd_recipient_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) and [smtpd_client_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions) variables.
You can test [here](http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/shopenrelaytest.php) if your server is an open relay.