# Catchall email server in amazon AWS

Tags: email-server, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catchall email to a single user mailbox in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/164105/how-to-catchall-email-to-a-single-user-mailbox-in-postfix)

I want to set up a Catchall email address for a system we are developing. We're thinking on using amazon AWS, but I need to know how can I setup this. Do I have to install postfix (for example) in an EC2 instance, or does amazon offer a service like SES but for receiving emails?

Thanks!

Comment: Amazon does not offer such a service. You can setup Postfix to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install `postfix` in an EC2 instance if you require a mail server - AWS has no facility to act as a mail server.

Amazon offer their own AMI (Amazon Machine Image) running a derivative of CentOS with a more up to date yum repository: `postfix` is currenty listed at version `2:2.6.6-2.11.amzn1`.